# webpack.config.js does not run for local packages in React app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json, yarn-workspaces

I've created local packages within my React typescript project and is meant not to publish but use just for the project separating from main code. I'm using workspaces so specify those local packages. I don't have any error running the app but when I do yarn build, it fails finding the package throwing error at importing the package to be not found. It turned out that on yarn build, local packages' webpack.config does not run. I concluded this after adding `include: /local_packages/` rule in root webpack.config file which didn't throw any error. So how can I make webpack of local packages run during yarn build so it would't throw error while importing them?

local package's webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  stats: {
    modulesSort: '!size',
  },
};
```